# Play Twilio Audio file

Tags: php, twilio

```
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
$calls = $client->account->calls;
foreach($calls as $call){
?>
<audio controls><source src='<?php echo "https://api.twilio.com".$call->uri; ?>' type='audio/ogg'><source src='<?php echo "https://api.twilio.com".$call->uri; ?>' type='audio/mpeg'> Your browser does not support the audio tag.</audio>
<?
}
?>
```

I tried appending .mp3 to the URL, it did not worked!

Comment: With the `autoplay` attribute, or is the `$client->uri` wrong? You're not very specific.

Comment: `$client->uri` doesn't look right at all. You should be able to find the mp3 URL from the each of the items in `$calls`.

Comment: Hey @philnash I have edited the code and also mentioned about the mp3

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Yes I had written the code incorrectly, now i have edited the code! Please check to it!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

My guess here is that you are trying to list out audio elements for calls that you have recorded so that you can play them back. If that is the case, then you are not using the correct URI for the recording. `$call->uri` will actually return the path of the API resource for the call itself.

Instead, you will need to list the recordings of the call and use the URLs returned there. Like so:

```
<?
  $client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
  $calls = $client->account->calls;
  foreach($calls as $call){
    foreach($call->recordings as $recording){
?>
  <audio controls>
    <source src='<?php echo "https://api.twilio.com".$recording->uri; ?>' type='audio/wav'>
    <source src='<?php echo "https://api.twilio.com".$recording->uri.".mp3"; ?>' type='audio/mpeg'>
    Your browser does not support the audio tag.
  </audio>
<?
    }
  }
?>
```